# How do I identify if a variable is in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables

How do I identify if a randomly selected variable is in a list?
Python 3

Example:

```
WarriorList = ['Achilles', 'Sun Wukong']
GuardianList = ['Ares', 'Ymir']
HunterList = ['Apollo', Artemis']
MageList = ['Anubis', 'ra']

Tank = ()

def TankPick():
    Tank = (random.choice(WarriorList))
    print (Tank)

def BalancePick():
    if (Tank) in WarriorList:
        print ('yes')
        print (random.choice(Magelist))
    else:
        print ('no')
        print (random.choice(Hunterlist))
```

Expected outcome:

```
'Sun Wukong'
'yes'
'ra'
```

or

```
'Ymir'
'no'
'Artemis'
```

Comment: You're missing a single quote on line 3 btw

Comment: Since the answer you're seeking doesn't depend on whether the target is random or not, I'm removing the `random` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I identify if a randomly selected variable is in a list? Python 3

Simple: `x in y`, where `x` is the element you want to check and `y` is your iterable of values.

There are some other problems with your code, though. You define two functions which are never called, neither one of which returns any value. You have a multiple `Tank` variables that won't work the way you seem to think they will. Those variables only live within the scope of their functions where they are defined. After the function finishes, the respective `Tank` variables are destroyed. The one you declare outside of the functions (in the "global scope") meanwhile is only once set to be an empty tuple and then never changed because, again, the other `Tank` variables are confined to their respective function scopes. If you absolutely must, you should declare them as `global` in the functions - or, even better yet, properly use them as function arguments and return values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what the final product is that you're working to, but I went ahead and did the best I could!

```
import random
WarriorList = ['Achilles', 'Sun Wukong']
GuardianList = ['Ares', 'Ymir']
HunterList = ['Apollo', 'Artemis']
MageList = ['Anubis', 'ra']

class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Tank = ()
    def TankPick(self):
        # Grabs a random name from all of the lists included
        self.Tank = (random.choice(WarriorList + GuardianList + HunterList + MageList))
        print (self.Tank)

    def BalancePick(self):
        if self.Tank in WarriorList:
            print ("yes\n" + random.choice(MageList))
            # \n is new line
        else:
            print ("no\n" + random.choice(HunterList))


cr = Container()
# Runs TankPick inside of Container
cr.TankPick()
# Runs BalancePick inside of Container after TankPick
cr.BalancePick()
```